# Stop and Restart SparkContext executing in deploy mode "cluster"

Tags: apache-spark, driver, cluster-computing, spark-submit

In order to fit the efficiency requirements, I am forced to stop SparkContext and restart it with a new configuration more optimal in terms of number of executors, memory per executor, executor memory overhead...

I can achieve this **launching my spark-submit in client mode** :

```
spark-submit --num-executors 5 \
--deploy-mode client \
--class className spark.jar
```

And then within my code executing:

```
spark.stop()

val spark2 : SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
.config("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
.config("spark.executor.instances", "8")
.getOrCreate()
```

And everything works OK.

However, when launching in **client** mode, stopping the SparkContext and restarting sparkContext in **cluster mode**, I get the following error:

```
20/05/28 18:05:24 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Detected yarn cluster mode, but isn't running on a cluster. Deployment to YARN is not supported directly by SparkContext. Please use spark-submit.
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:379)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/05/28 18:05:24 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$postApplicationEnd(SparkContext.scala:2416)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1931)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1385)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1930)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:585)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have also tried launching spark-submit in **cluster mode**, stopping SparkCOntext and restarting it again in cluster mode. In this case I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1583287354042_80626 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1171)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1608)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am not sure if it might be related to the fact that the driver is running on the cluster...

I'd be very grateful if someone could provide a solution to achieve these requirements.